# How to use Samsung TV as a remote display over lan cable connection

Tags: lan, desktop, cable, screencasts, smart-tv

I have a desktop PC with no WiFi and a Samsung TV [[ES6710](http://media.technicmarket.rs/2012/09/UE-32-ES-67103.jpg)] that can stream media using DLNA, however I want to use it as a remote display over LAN to mirror my PC's desktop on the TV *(I have ethernet pre-wired within walls)*.

- I know about Chrome Cast and also tried doing so via an IPTV [application](https://siptv.app/news/) and [VLC stream](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html) over HTTP, which worked as expected but lagged with a ~30s delay
- Majority of casting applications are used for streaming media files via LAN, rather than using the smart TV as a projector, with [miracast](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15053/windows-8-project-wireless-screen-miracast) doing the exact same thing in Windows over WiFi
- HDMI to LAN converters could be an alternative, but I would then have to connect to the TV using two LAN cables

Is there a solution which is:

1. LAN ⟷ LAN || LAN ⟷ Switch ⟷ LAN?
2. An application for Windows?
3. Able to steam the computer's desktop (Skype, Discord, TeamViewer screen capture)?
4. Able to provide desktop video transcoding on the fly?

Comment: Question: Has the TV also normal (non-LAN) inputs? IN which case you could just connect DP or HDMI via a cable and no additonal programs are needed.

Comment: Yep, the outputs are showed above on 6710. http://media.technicmarket.rs/2012/09/UE-32-ES-67103.jpg I want to use the LAN port because it will be easier for my dad not to configure e.g chrome-cast of any hardware of the sort. So it this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a [Steam link device](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5613-TADC-2802) for screen sharing over ethernet:

- Newer Samsung TV's have Steam link applications available and was mainly developed for streaming video games from PC → TV, with it working pretty well for screen sharing too (minimize big picture functionality).

Answer (score 0):

I bought another TV intended just for streaming over the home network. I am currently using 6710 as monitor over HDMI and a TV. Works like a charm with a better cable directly to the PC.